How to Include Crystal Reports MSI package in VS2022 Setup project
I am trying to create a set up project in Visual Studio 2022 for my VB.Net WinForms application. I am using Crystal Reports. I have downloaded "CR13SP32MSI64_0-80007712.MSI" from SAP Crystal Report website and I have installed it in my machine. Now I want to deploy my applications to my clients machines.
In the setup project, How I can include this msi package ? So that I can deploy my application in the client machines without installing crystal reports there.
Since our machine is 64 bit, there is no merge modules are available. Instead SAP says to use MSI packages.
My Question is How I can include the crystal report .msi package in the VS 2022 setup project ?
Please help.
